# Reading and Writing to BMP file

Tags: c++, fread, bmp, ofstream

I'm new to C++ and programming.  I have the following flawed code to read from a BMP file and Write to another BMP file. I did not want to use any external libraries.

I have an 800kb 24bit bmp file. mybmp.bmp. Will try and upload it to dropbox.

```
`#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;


unsigned char* editing(char* filename)  
{
    int i;
int j;
FILE* mybmpfilespointer;
mybmpfilespointer = fopen(filename, "rb");
unsigned char headerinfo[54];
fread(headerinfo, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, mybmpfilespointer); // read the 54-byte header size_t fread ( void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );

// extract image height and width from header
int width = *(int*)&headerinfo[18];
int height = *(int*)&headerinfo[22];

int size = 3 * width * height;
unsigned char* imagesdata = new unsigned char[size]; // allocate 3 bytes per pixel
fread(imagesdata, sizeof(unsigned char), size, mybmpfilespointer); // read the rest of the imagesdata at once

// display image height and width from header
 cout << " width:" << width << endl;
cout << " height:" << height << endl;

ofstream arrayfile("bmpofstream.bmp"); // File Creation 

for(int a = 0; a < 53; a++) //bgr to rgb
{
    arrayfile << headerinfo[a];
}

for(int k=0; k<size; k++)
{
    arrayfile<<imagesdata[k]<<endl; //Outputs array to file
}
arrayfile.close();

delete[] mybmpfilespointer;
delete[] imagesdata;
fclose(mybmpfilespointer);
return imagesdata;
return headerinfo;


}

int main()
{

FILE* mybmpfilespointer = fopen("mybmp.bmp", "rb");
if (mybmpfilespointer)
{

     editing("mybmp.bmp");
 }
 else
 {
     cout << "Cant Read File";
 }

}`
```

As you can see I read from **mybmp.bmp** which is 819680bytes

and write to **bmpofstream.bmp** as it is.

But somehow the resulting file is exactly 3x times the size of the **mybmp** around 2460826bytes.

I read header from **mybmp** file as **headerinfo**.
and
data from **mybmp** as **imagesdata**.

When I write to **bmpofstream.bmp** these arrays it is a messed up bmp file.

1) I'm guessing the increase in filesize is related to reading individual pixels and writing them 3 times or something but couldnt figure out. Why do you think this would be?

2) Once I figure out how to read and write this file as it is, I wanted to modify it. So I might as well ask this now:

I wanted to modify this image so that I can increase the value of each pixel by 50, so this would end up in a darker image. Can I do this directly as:

```
 for(j = 0; j < size; j++) 
  {
     imagesdata[j]=imagesdata[j]+50;
   }
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking a look at some existing library, even if you want to code yourself you may learn a lot. See for example libbmp source code,
https://code.google.com/p/libbmp/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

void editing( char* filename )
{
    std::ifstream input( filename, std::ios::binary );

    if( !input.is_open() )
    {
        std::cout << "Can`t open file" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // copies all data into buffer
    std::vector<char> buffer( ( std::istreambuf_iterator<char>( input ) ), ( std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() ) );
    input.close();

    std::vector<char> headerinfo;
    {
        auto it = std::next( buffer.begin(), 54 );
        std::move( buffer.begin(), it, std::back_inserter( headerinfo ) );
        buffer.erase( buffer.begin(), it );
    }
    // extract image height and width from header
    int width = *reinterpret_cast<int*>( (char*)headerinfo.data() + 18 );
    int height = *reinterpret_cast<int*>( (char*)headerinfo.data() + 22 );

    int size = 3 * width * height;


    std::vector<char> imagesdata;
    {
        auto it = std::next( buffer.begin(), size );
        std::move( buffer.begin(), it, std::back_inserter( imagesdata ) );
        buffer.erase( buffer.begin(), it );
    }
    // display image height and width from header
    std::cout << " width:" << width << std::endl;
    std::cout << " height:" << height << std::endl;

    // paste your code here 
    // ...
    std::ofstream arrayfile( "bmpofstream.bmp" ); // File Creation 

    std::ostream_iterator<char> output_iterator( arrayfile );
    std::copy( headerinfo.begin(), headerinfo.end(), output_iterator ); // write header to file
    std::copy( imagesdata.begin(), imagesdata.end(), output_iterator ); // write image data to file
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    editing( argv[1] );
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why the OP should "try it"? Why not explain what the differences are / what you changed or fixed / what this code actually does? It's a bit like, you know, you get a pill from a guy in Amsterdam an' he says, like, "try this, dude". You going to swallow it?